# AngularJS ng-class function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

SUMMARY:
Why is tab() being called multiple times?

DETAILS:
I am reviewing a tutorial from spring.io.
[http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/]

It has sample code available.  In that code there is an AngularJS section looks like this:

```
<li ng-class="active:tab('home')"><a href="#/">home</a></li>
<li><a href="login">login</a></li>
<li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="" ...>logout</a></li>
...
<div ng-view class="container"></div>
```

The tab() is resolved in a Javascript file:

```
$scope.tab = function(route) { 
    return $route.current && route === route.current.controller; 
}
```

In other words, if the "home" is the active view (home.html and the home controller) then make the Bootstrap class "active:true".

The "home" controller has this:

```
.controller("home", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('resource/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    })
});
```

The home.html is:

```
<h1>Greeting</h1>
<div ng-show="authenticated">
    <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="!authenticated">
    <p>Login to see your greeting</p>
</div>
```

When the page is first loaded the .config() makes "home" the current provider and "home.html" to be templateUrl.  The files are loaded but the view (for storing home.html) isn't yet loaded.  I see tab() called:
Once when the the menu is loaded (home, login, logout) and displayed.
After two more times the logout menu choice is gone (depended on being authenticated, which we are not).  The full home.html is displayed:

```
home    login

Greeting
The ID is {{greeting.id}}
The content is {{greeting.content}}
Login to see your greeting.
```

Now the resource is called (it will fail for authentication reasons) but the success() isn't called.

Tab() is called again, after which the {{greeting.id}} and {{greeting.content}} diasappear (replaced with blanks).

Now tab() is called six more times, after which the AngularJS events are done.

By my reckoning, tab() should be called only once because it refers to an anchor link.  Yet it seems to be called for everything AngularJS is doing to index.html and home.html.

Can someone explain why AngularJS likes calling tab() so much?

Comment: That's how Angular's digest cycle works.

Comment: Please, explain the logic behind _"should be called only once because it refers to an anchor link"_. The function will be called anytime something happens. (simplified version)